# Detectar si la orientación es vertical u horizontal

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Quiero aplicar diferentes estilos CSS dependiendo de si la orientación del dispositivo es vertical (modo retrato o *portrait*) u horizontal (modo apaisado o *landscape*). ¿Se puede lograr sólo con CSS?

¿Hay alguna alternativa? Supongo que siempre se podría detectar el ancho y alto de la ventana con JavaScript y a partir de ahí decidir qué estilos aplicar, pero me pregunto si hay algún modo más sencillo que use sólo CSS (si no, estaría bien una solución con JS).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Teóricamente es posible solo con css, me refiero a teórico porque nunca lo he intentado:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }

@media all and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Algo de documentación en [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation) y [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation).

Según la especificación de w3:

> La orientación es **portrait** cuando el valor de height (altura) del viewport es mayor o igual al de width (ancho), de lo contrario la orientación será **landscape**.

Hay una nota bastante interesante en la documentación de MDN:

> Hay que tener en cuenta que al mostrarse el teclado en un dispositivo móvil en modo **portrait**, es posible que el viewport sea más ancho que alto, por lo cual el navegador puede utilizar los estilos de **landscape** en ese momento, y no los de **portrait**.

---

Algunas alternativas:

- Evento [orientationchange](https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/) de jQuery Mobile
- Evento [orientationchange](https://compat.spec.whatwg.org/#event-orientationchange) "nativo" (actualmente no plenamente implementado).

Answer (score 5):

En CSS3 existe en `media` la opcion `orientation`

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
  ... 
}
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
  ...
}
```

Ejemplo

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 height: 100%;
}
.demo-wrappper {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.demo-wrappper h1 {
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;

 display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
 body {
  background: #00C203;
 }
 .demo-wrappper .landscape {
  display: none;
 }
}
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
 body {
  background-color: #F08B48;
 }
 .demo-wrappper .portrait {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-wrappper css-orientation">
 <h1 class="portrait">Portrait</h1>
 <h1 class="landscape">Landscape</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Al momento la mejor forma de hacerlo en Javascript es por medio de la API `window.matchMedia()` <sup>[(doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)</sup> ya que cuenta con una optima compatibilidad con los navegadores. Aun así, en el caso de que se utilice un navegador nuevo o poco convencional, no está mal añadir una condición `else` que ofrezca una solución alternativa como la que recomiendo a continuación.

Comparando el alto y el ancho del dispositivo se puede determinar su orientación en base al valor más alto, la desventaja de este método es que puede fallar si el teclado del dispositivo está desplegado ya que algunos navegadores restan el espacio que ocupa el teclado a estos valores alterando el resultado. Pero si el control es efectuado al momento de cargar la pagina este problema no subsiste, de modo que esta parece ser una excelente opción B.

Código:

```js
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", ()=> {
    console.log(getOrientation());
});

function getOrientation() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
        var current_mode = 'Portrait';
    }
    else if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
        var current_mode = 'Landscape';
    }
    else {
        var current_mode = window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight ? "Portrait" : "Landscape";
    }
    return current_mode
};
```

Answer (score 0):

En javascript podes hacer:

```js
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", ()=> {
    console.log(window.screen.orientation);
});

if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
    /// portrait codigo
}

if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
   /// landscape codigo
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido! Gracias por contribuir! ¿Podrías explicar brevemente lo que hace `window.matchMedia()`. Además, ¿los `if`s no deberían estar dentro del evento?